# Android Time Picker (change clock hand Color programmatically)

Tags: android, timepicker

I have created a time Picker with below style. **colorControlActivated** will set the clock hand Color*(reference : http://www.zoftino.com/android-timepicker-example)*. But during run time is there a way to set this color programmatically.

> *Consider a scenario: If I select a time, less than current time then the clock hand color should change to RED color.*

```
 <style name="AlertDialogDatePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one.**

MainActivity.class

```
TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogDatePicker));
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.AlertDialogDatePicker));
```

I've found my own answer and it is quite simple. When instaciating the TimePicker and DatePicker send as parameter a new AlertDialogDatePicker with the custom style you want in order to change the style.

Comment: Creating a new instance and applying style can do it. But i don't want to create a new instance. instead i want to update on the existing instance.( like how we dynamically update the text color, similar way i have to update the clock hand color)